# Theano-cache clear in Anaconda spyder

Tags: python, anaconda, theano

I first installed Anaconda on Win8 64bits correctly, then installed `Theano` by `pip install theano` from windows console. As I run the code in spyder IPython console, it asks me to clear theano cache(`theano-cache clear`). So I typed `theano-cache clear` in IPython console, but it shows invalid syntax.
Can anybody show me where I have done wrong? Or how can I clear theano cache in this case?
Thanks in advance.

BTW, the file theano-cache is in C:\Program Files\Anaconda2\Scripts, there is not a bin folder in C:\Program Files\Anaconda2\Lib\site-packages\theano.

Comment: @vishes_shell Thanks for helping editing the question!

Comment: In every OS you have terminal, program where you can write scripts and etc(e.g. https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Terminal_(macOS) )

Answer (score 1):

You need to run `theano-cache clear` in your shell not IPython. As it says in the [docs](http://deeplearning.net/software/theano/install.html#updating-theano)

Comment: Thanks. But I tried to run `theano-cache clear` in python console, anaconda prompt and IPython console, all end up in invalid syntax... I don't know where I got wrong...

Comment: @jenng1000000 You need to do this in our shell/terminal, not python interpreter.

Comment: @vishes_shell: what do you mean by shell/terminal? cmd? Can you be more specific of where to put these commands?

Comment: @jenng1000000 i hope you will have solved the problem by now, but for completion, i've edited vishes_shell's answer for clarity. What they are calling "shell" is what you called your "windows console" – hope that helps!